# Обязательно ли прописывать view ID для каждой view в файле xml layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view, layout

Только начал изучать работу с андроид и изучаю xml-layout. 
Интересует вопрос, обязательно ли задавать значение полю `android:id` в разметке для каждого `View`, если я не собираюсь потом использовать этот объект `View`?

Comment: нет, но в некоторых Layout вам нужно будет связывать по id

Comment: Какие поля обязательны вам подскажет Android Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, задавать `id` для каждого элемента не обязательно.

Однако, есть отдельные классы разметки (например, `ConstraintLayout`), которые требуют задавать `id` всем или почти всем сложенным в них элементам.

Кроме того, Android умеет самостоятельно восстанавливать состояние экрана после, к примеру, блокировки, если для восстанавливаемых `View` и всех их "родителей" заданы `id`.

"родители" - это те `View`, внутри которых находятся другие `View`, например, так:

```
<FrameLayout
    ....>

    <TextView .../>
</FrameLayout>
```

Здесь `FrameLayout` является родителем `TextView`

Если текущая верстка не требует от Вас задания `id` всем элементам и Вам не нужна попытка системы автоматически восстановить состояние полей - то можете совершенно спокойно не проставлять `id`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Сижу изучаю, очень трудно на первый взгляд, много непонятных моментов, но благодаря тому, что могу тут спросить, чуть проясняется кое что.

Comment: @MaximPoleshchuk если ответ помог Вам разобраться - не забудьте отметить его принятым) Это позволит другим людям с той же проблемой быстрее найти ответ